# How to edit and save existing HTML using Python?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to write a program that enables someone to edit html from python 'input()' questions. For example: change a paragraph from the command line in python. Is there some sort of library I can use to read html then edit and save it?

Comment: check out the Beautiful Soup python lib.

Comment: Definitely a good one. but if you are looking for a portable script you can use the HTMLParser class from the html.parser library (built in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since an HTML file is just a plain text file it can be opened by python without the need for any extra libraries and such. Just open the file, edit what you need and write it.

Check out the following link:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Comment: Yah, but that does not deal with navigating all the tags